# Get Users Persona Information

Tags: xdb, experience-profile

How can I get a user's persona information in code when I am requesting the information not as the user but as someone else, e.g. a site administrator??

I have looked at how the Best Pattern match works in the Experience Profile but this process is very complicated, uses a crazy number of pipelines and does not provide a simple method to hook into.

Has anyone done something like this before?

Using Sitecore 8.1, ideally I would like to retrieve that values stored against the user. Not to worried about the best pattern/profile matched but you can get extra points for suggesting a solution to this.

Comment: 1) What Sitecore version are you on? 2) Do you need to get the best matching persona? Or the best matching pattern card?

Comment: more info added to question

Answer (score 2):

You can retrieve contact's behavioural information with the help of `ContactRepository` which is the recommended way to work with contact data in the situation you described (requesting information as not the website user).

```
    var repository = Factory.CreateObject("tracking/contactRepository", true) as ContactRepositoryBase;
    var contact = repository.LoadContactReadOnly(ID.NewID);

    foreach (IBehaviorProfileContext behaviorProfile in contact.BehaviorProfiles.Profiles)
    {
        var profileScores = behaviorProfile.Scores;
        ID patternId = behaviorProfile.PatternId;
        //and other properties                
    }
```

It returns contact data from xDB (MongoDB). Data representation in *Contacts* collection:

[image]

Hope it helps.